# Numbering elements in a list of vectors in clojure

Tags: list, vector, clojure

I have a list of vectors I want to number. For instance, I have the following
list of vectors

```
(["blah1" "blah2" "blah3"]
 ["clah1" "clah2" "clah3"]
 ["flah1" "flah2" "flah3"])
```

and would like something this:

```
(["line 1" "blah1" "blah2" "blah3"]
 ["line 2" "clah1" "clah2" "clah3"]
 ["line 3" "flah1" "flah2" "flah3"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map-indexed` can do the trick.

```
(map-indexed (fn [i v]
               (into [(str "line " (inc i))] v))
             [["blah1" "blah2" "blah3"]
              ["clah1" "clah2" "clah3"]
              ["flah1" "flah2" "flah3"]])
;; => (["line 1" "blah1" "blah2" "blah3"] ["line 2" "clah1" "clah2" "clah3"] ["line 3" "flah1" "flah2" "flah3"])
```

Answer (score 2):

map takes several sequences as last argument:

```
user=> (map vector (iterate inc 1) '(a b c d))
([1 a] [2 b] [3 c] [4 d])
```

Comment: you could also do `(map vector (rest (range)) '(a b c d))`